# Find and select image files from webpage

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

For some reason, I feel like this is a bit messy and could be cleaner. Any suggestions?

I'm selecting any image files ending in `.png` or `.jpg`, and removing any image source files that contains avatar (meaning it's a header image or an avatar).

```
def self.images(url)
  proxy_addr = 'http://localhost:'
  proxy_port = 8080
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), proxy: "#{proxy_addr}#{proxy_port}")
  images = doc.css('img[src$="jpg"], img[src$="png"]').select do |uri|
    uri['src'] =~ %r{^http://(\d+|media)}
  end
  images.map { |uri| uri['src'] }.reject { |uri| uri =~ /avatar/ }
end
```

Comment: Perhaps some added white space could help

Comment: Between ```proxy_port``` and ```doc``` would help a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in hard-coding `proxy_addr` and `proxy_port` separately, then concatenating them using interpolation.  On the other hand, it *would* be useful to make the proxy configurable.  One way is to use a default parameter:

```
def self.images(url, proxy='http://localhost:8080')
  doc = …
end
```

(Personally, I'd choose to have `proxy` default to `nil`, but the formulation above preserves compatibility with your existing code.)

---

You appear to be using the `open` function that is provided by [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).  You have a bug: the proxy needs to be specified as an option to `open` rather than to [`Nokogiri#HTML`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html#method-c-HTML).  Furthermore, opening the stream like that makes it impossible to close it properly.  I suggest using a block instead:

```
def self.images(url, proxy=nil)
  open(url, proxy: proxy) do |io|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(io)
    …
  end
end
```

---

Your regular expression should be case-insensitive when it looks for `http:`, as recommended by [RFC 3986 Sec 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1):

> An implementation should accept uppercase letters as equivalent to lowercase in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http") for the sake of robustness but should only produce lowercase scheme names for consistency.

Furthermore, hostnames are case-insensitive, as stated in [RFC 1035 Sec 2.3.3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) (though clarified by [RFC 4343 Sec 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4343#section-2)):

> For all parts of the DNS that are part of the official protocol, all
> comparisons between character strings (e.g., labels, domain names, etc.)
> are done in a case-insensitive manner.

Also consider allowing URLs that start with `https:`.

---

The parameter to your two blocks should not be named `uri`, but rather `img`, after the `<img>` tags that your CSS-style selector requested.

The way you sequence `select`, `map`, and `reject` is awkward.  I suggest

```
doc.css('img[src$="jpg"], img[src$="png"]').map do |img|
  img['src']
end.select do |uri|
  uri =~ %r{^https?://(\d+|media)}i and uri !~ /avatar/
end
```

Comment: You always give solid advice, thanks for the insight. I'll review the post again when I wake up. It's late! One last thing, could you explain why defaulting the proxy to nil is a better alternative and the regex ```i and uri !~```?

Comment: If no proxy is specified, I'd expect it to make a direct HTTP request, just like any computer would behave out of the box if you didn't configure it.

Comment: I see, what about the regex? I've never seen ```i and !~``` is that valid?

Comment: `/pattern/i` means [ignore case](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Options).  `!~` is a [negative regexp match operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13759167/1157100). You could also write it as `… and not uri =~ /avatar/` instead.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the great advice once again.